# How to parse the img src link from <![CDATA]> by nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, xml, rubygems

There is a XML response, how can I parse the img src link from `<![CDATA]>` by nokogiri

```
<description>
        <![CDATA[<img src="https://ebcnews.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2017/02/24/14879207313348jzJ88NZUPf.jpg" />]]>

      <![CDATA[
      <p>
      This is content
      </p>
      ]]>
</description>
```

I use the code pare the XML response, but it only return  `<p>This is content</p>`, anyone know how to parse the `<![CDATA]>` image src link?

```
xml_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body.force_encoding("UTF-8"))
xml_doc.xpath("//description").each do |ele|
  p ele
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you expect parsing XML document with `HTML` parser would produce any result?

```
#                   ⇓⇓⇓
xml_doc = Nokogiri::XML(response.body.force_encoding("UTF-8"))

xml_doc.xpath("//description")
       .children
       .select { |e| Nokogiri::XML::CDATA === e }
       .first
       .content
#⇒ "<img src=... />"
```